# Linux: Clone harddrive to external USB stick

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, clone

I would like to clone a whole linux OS from the harddrive to an external USB stick. However, I don't want to clone all the unused part of the harddrive, only the used part.
The partitions on the harddrive look like this (`lsblk`)

```
sda
- sda1 512M /boot/efi
- sda2 1K
- sda5 223,1G /
```

With `df -H`:

```
/dev/sda5 235G 14G 210G /
/dev/sda1 536M 6,4M 530M /boot/efi
```

As you can see, only 14G are occupied so there is no reason that this whole OS doesn't fit on my 32GB USB-Stick.

The question now is - how can I do this as user friendly as possible? I tried Clonezilla and gave up after 4h of not being able to read my external USB stick and / or not being able to clone the data to another computer.

Comment: what's the filesystem type? ext4?

Comment: For cloning the amou8nt of unused space within a partition is immaterial. And you can only clone to a drive of the same size or bigger. If you want to do what you described then first you must resize, shrink, `sda5` so that the whole space of all the required partitions does NOT exceed the size of the target drive. It's that simple.

Comment: It sounds like you don’t want to clone the disk but to make a copy of the used file system. Best bet is a tool like `rsync ` with appropriate exclusions so you don’t try to copy /dev, /proc, /sys, etc.